# Using cin to read blank line

Tags: c++

Hi I am working on a program that takes in data from a user inputted line and prints out certain things

Here is my pseudocode, I can't post my full code so I will try to translate it.

The input should be in one line like:

```
close door then whatever
```

My problem comes when I need a newline. I want the program to stop when there is an empty new line. I tried using getline but then the input only works when its like

```
close
door then whatever
```

(assume that these are randoms words)

When I need my input to be like the first one and Stop when there is a new line. How do I solve this?

```
string a;
string b;
string c;
string d;

cin>>a>>b;


while(1){

if(a == "close"){//assume that a could be a bunch of words that do different things
     cin>>c>>d>>endl;
     //do whatever if string a == open
}

else if(a.empty()){ // This is where my problem is
    return 0;
}

}
```

Comment: You said "I tried using getline" in the question but there's no `getline` in the code you posted.

Comment: When I used getline the Input was on two lines when I needed the typed input to be on one.

Comment: The question is unclear. In the first input example `close door then whatever` there's no "new line" except at the end of the line (after the "whatever" word); and `getline` should stop there. Post your actual program and describe its current behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You do not reference getline in your code, have you tried:

```
std::getline(std::cin, a);
```

Comment: When I use getline then the input becomes two lines, not one line. I need to have the input be in one line.

Comment: What you may want to do then is get the whole line into 'a'. Then, break a into 4 segments based on the space. So, a becomes, "Close door then whatever." Then you parse it into the variable a,b,c, and d.